# How to get data in function extend controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My controller is like this:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends EX_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['news'] = $this->dashboard_model->get_news();
        $this->load->view('dashboard/index_view', $this->data);
    }
```

My EX_Controller is like this :

```
<?php
class EX_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $data;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('notification_model');
        $this->get_notification();
    }

    public function get_notification()
    {
        $session = $this->session->userdata('login');
        $this->data['notification'] = $this->notification_model->get($session);
        $this->data['count_notification'] = $this->notification_model->get_count_notification($session['customer_id']);
    }
}
?>
```

My index view is like this :

```
<?php
    foreach ($notification as $value) {
?>
        <li>
        <?php
            echo '<a href='.base_url().'notification/notif/'.$value['notification_id'].'>';
        ?>
                <span class="time">
                <?php 
                    echo time_elapsed($value['notification_created_date']); 
                ?>
                </span>
                <span class="details">
                    <span class="label label-sm label-icon label-info">
                        <i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>
                    </span> <?php echo $value['notification_message']; ?>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

When executed, there exist error :

```
Message:  Undefined variable: count_notification
Message:  Undefined variable: notification
```

It seems it can not call get_notification function in EX Controller

I put in function `get_notification(EX Controller)` to be read in all controllers

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Where is `$data` defined ?

Comment: @meda, No `$data`, but `$this->data`. I want get `$this->data['notification']` and `$this->data['count_notification']` in `function get_notification` (EX_Controller). Then send it to the index_view.

Comment: yes but I don't see where in your code did you declare that property, it should also be public `public $data;`

Comment: @meda, I add `public $data;` in `EX_Controller` like this : `<?php
    class EX_Controller extends CI_Controller
    {
        public $data;
        public function __construct()
        {    
        ...`. But, It's not working

Comment: @moses_toh where in your code do  you call get_notification

Comment: @meda, Thank you very much. It's working. Look my update question. I had update. Btw, without `public $data;`, It's working

Comment: Nice, should i post an aswer so we can close your question?

Comment: @meda, Yeah. Post you answer. So, we can close my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to just use this:

```
$this->load->model('notification_model'); 
$this->get_notification();
```

Comment: I try it without `public $data;`. It's working. So, I just use this: `$this->load->model('notification_model'); $this->get_notification();`

Comment: Just use this: `$this->load->model('notification_model'); $this->get_notification();`. Without `$data`, it's working. I had update your answer

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189488/how-to-remove-single-quotes-in-prepare-statement